# Find the first non-recurring character in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, programming-challenge

I wrote a solution to [first-unique-character-in-a-string](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-unique-character-in-a-string/):

> Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return its index. If it doesn't exist, return -1.

If there is better way for me to build the dictionary `seems`? and find the first key when `value` is 1 and `index` is lowest?

```
def firstUniqChar(string) -> int:
    seems = dict()
    index = len(string)
    c = ''
    for i, char in string:
        if char not in seems:
            seems.setdefault(char, (i,1))
        else:
            seems[char] = (seems[char][0], seems[char][1] + 1)

    for k, value in seems.items():
        if value[1] == 1 and value[0] < index:
            index = value[0]
            c = k
    return  index if c else -1
```

Answer (score 6):

The code is too convoluted and unreadable for such a simple task

- `seems` is a dictionary where the values are (first index, occurrences) pairs.  That's an unconventional data structure.  You'd be better off with two separate dictionaries.
- `seems` is a weird variable name.  What does it mean, anyway?
- Why is the `index = len(string)` statement necessary?

This solution is less cluttered, and more clearly expresses the idea that you are counting the characters, then finding the first unique one.

```
from collections import Counter

def first_uniq_char(s):
    counts = Counter(s)
    return next((i for i, c in enumerate(s) if counts[c] == 1), -1)
```